# How to retrieve substring form a string using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, csv, python-3.x

I have data of the form

```
CS989_-RED814298959
CS663_RED812657324
RED819238322_CS537
......
```

This data is in csv file. I want  to retrieve all the sub strings starting with RED.
Please suggest me a way to do this using regular expression in python

I tried following code:

```
import re
string="RED819238322_CS537"
substring=re.match("[a-zA-Z]*//([0-9]*)",string)
```

It's returning None

Comment: Put what you have tried in your question please.

Comment: What's a "substring" ? Could you post the expected results for your example input ?

Comment: There is no `//` in your data, why do you expect this to match?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Output should be a list ["RED814298959",RED812657324,RED819238322]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Help on function match in module re:
>
> match(pattern, string, flags=0)
>       Try to apply the pattern **at the start of the string**, returning
>       a match object, or None if no match was found.

You want `re.search` or `re.findall` instead. Also your regexp is incorrect - if what you want is just "RED" followed by any number of digits, it's spelled `r"RED[0-9]+"`

```
>>> strings
['CS989_-RED814298959', 'CS663_RED812657324', 'RED819238322_CS537']
>>> re.match(r"(RED[0-9]+)", strings[0])
>>> re.findall(r"(RED[0-9]+)", strings[0])
['RED814298959']
>>> re.findall(r"(RED[0-9]+)", strings[1])
['RED812657324']
>>> re.findall(r"(RED[0-9]+)", strings[2])
['RED819238322']
>>> re.search(r"(RED[0-9]+)", strings[0])
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1772e40>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need regex, don't use regex.

```
with open('myfile') as f:
    print([l for l in f if l.startswith('RED')])
```

changing as necessary, i.e. with `csv.reader`:

```
with open('myfile') as f:
    print([row for row in csv.reader(f) if row[0].startswith('RED')])
```

Comment: I can not use "startwith" because  sometimes sub string comes in between

Answer (score 0):

What are those slashes doing in there? Try this:

```
substring=re.match("[a-zA-Z]*([0-9]*)", string)
```